# How can I save the required pixel from an image and draw the image using that pixels

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have written a sample code to find out the black color pixels from an image, now I would like to save all those pixels to an array and would like to save that particular image with the save pixels can some one help me

Assume my image that I am getting the pixels is as follows

I will read all the black pixels and would like to save them, from that I would like to re-image the `Fallout` with transparent background. This is what I have written

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Height; j++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = b.GetPixel(i, j);

                Response.Write("The color is " + pixelColor);

                if (pixelColor.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
                {
                    //Will get black color here
                }
            }
        }
```

Can some one help me out for the remaining.

Comment: Instead of creating a new image from the according pixels, modify the existing image. Set all pixels that are not black to transparent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx

Comment: Hi `Nico Schertler` I did as per said but when I am having signature with blue color the image is not converting to transparent

Answer (score 0):

Create a second bitmap with the same size

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(oldBitmap.Width, oldBitmap.Height);
```

You can compare the colors directly

```
if (pixeColor == Color.Black) {
```

Inside the `if { }`

```
newBitmap.SetPixel(...);
```

That's it, but if you just wan't a transparent version, you can use `Bitmap.MakeTransparent(Color);`

PS: GetPixel() and SetPixel() are extremely slow, try using unsafe bitmap access